# Menu Strip usercontrol that adds items to form at design time

Tags: c#, winforms

My goal is to emulate the Smart tag already on the menustrip in visual studio that inserts the common menu items.

I'd like to have the user be able to select the item they want from a drop down (I have that already using a UITypeEditor) and then have the items created just like they normally would be at design time (part of the form's components with their creation code in the .Designer.cs file).

The best I have been able to do is to have the menustrip control create the items and add them to it's Items collection. The problem is that the items can't be manipulated further at design time. The menu containing them is actually 'locked'. For the user to add more buttons they would have to do it dynamically at run time.

Is my goal possible and if so could some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: I believe I can help you, let me get back to you in a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I'm not positive, but I think you need to interact with the [IComponentChangedService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice.oncomponentchanged.aspx) and inform it that your menu has changed. It's been a while since I've written design time support for controls.</s>

In your designer:

```
IComponentChangeService changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
```

**Actually**

I think it is the DesignHost you need check out this:

```
IDesignerHost designHost = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
designHost.Container.Add(...)
```

I believe you have to add your component to it to manage it.